# What is a simple way to check if two git repositories are unrelated?

Tags: git

What is a simple way to check if two git repositories are unrelated?

For example let's assume we cloned following repositories:

- https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

How can I check that one doesn't share history with another?

How can I check that one share partial history with another? How can I browse common DAG and view difference?

Note: Git allows shallow copy + repositories history can diverge with a time...

Comment: Before you go dumpster diving, is there any way that you could ask the maintainers of the two projects if they have anything in common?  I mean, if one is a fork of the other, I would expect this to be known.

Comment: You could compare the Sha1 of the first commit of each repository. If it's not the same, they are not related. If it's the same, they are/were (but perhaps diverge too much, something you should find a way to evaluate...)

Comment: Here, we could see that they are related...

Comment: @Philippe As I wrote one repository can be a shallow copy of another. It is not a reliable source.

Answer (score 3):

You can clone the first one, then add the second one as a additional remote:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic
cd spring-framework-petclinic
git remote add other https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
git fetch --all
```

Then you can browse both DAGs:

```
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
```

And see if they have any common history by looking at the merge base of two trunks:

```
git merge-base origin/master other/master
```

Comment: How can I clean repository after `git fetch --all other`?

Comment: You can simply remove the remote: `git remote rm other`, this will remove the references, if you want to clean the object before they are gc'ed in the future, you can force a gc: `git -c gc.reflogExpire=now gc --prune=all` (WARNING: this will remove ALL stale objects)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to prove that two repositories *are* related: if they contain matching commits—commits with the same hash IDs and contents, although "same hash IDs" is usually sufficient<sup>1</sup>—they are related.

As you note, it's much harder to prove that they are *un*-related unless they are both complete (non-shallow, non-single-branch) clones.  If both are complete, yet neither has any commit in common with the other, the two repositories are unrelated.

If you have both repositories and verify that both are complete, simply enumerate all the commit hash IDs in both repositories and look for common IDs.  If common IDs exist, the two are probably related.  To enumerate all the commit hash IDs, run `git rev-list --all` (redirect output to file or to program that reads both sets of outputs and checks for common hash IDs).

See footnote 1 for eliminating "probably", but the TL;DR is that for now, any two identical IDs means shared history.

---

<sup>1</sup>Given a uniform hash function *h(k)* whose range is *r = |{h(k)|*, the probability of an accidental collision of hashes for two distinct keys *k<sub>1</sub>*, *k<sub>2</sub>* is *p = 1/r*.  The probability of uniqueness is the complement of this is *p̄ = 1 - (1/r)*.  Generalizing to *n* keys and using a two-term Taylor expansion of *e<sup>x</sup> ≈ 1 + x* for *x ≪ 1*, we get *p̄ ≈ e<sup>(-n(n-1)) / 2r</sup>*, as long as *r* is reasonably large.

Git's hash function is currently SHA1, which has a pretty uniform distribution and has r = 2<sup>160</sup> = 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976.  This satisfies our formula, which means we can use the approximation.

Hence, if you sum up the total number of hashes *n* and plug it in to the formula:

```
r=1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976
1 - exp(-n*(n-1)/(2*r))
```

(remember, we want p, not p-bar),
you get the probability of a collision.  To check for an actual collision, of course, you can just compare the underlying actual objects: if the hashes match, compare the objects directly to detect a collision.  But it's *extremely* unlikely in the first place.  If we take two repositories that, together, contain ten million commits, we compute:

```
$ bc -l
r=2^160
n=10*1000*1000
scale=100
1 - e(-n*(n-1)/(2*r))
.0000000000000000000000000000000000342113848680412753525884397196522\
895097282878872708411144841034243
```

which as you can see is still pretty tiny.  It's not until we get to:

```
n=10*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000
```

(ten sextillion objects, using the short scale notation)

that we find:

```
1 - e(-n*(n-1)/(2*r))
.0000342108030863093209851036344159518189002166758764416221121344549\
079733424124497666779807175655625
```

a noticeable chance of accidental collision, at about 0.0035%.  At 100 sextillion objects we are up to a 0.35% chance:

```
n=100*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000*1000
1 - e(-n*(n-1)/(2*r))
.0034152934013810288444649336362559390942558976421984312395097770719\
923433072593638116228277476790795
```

and by 1 septillion objects we're running some serious risks:

```
1 - e(-n*(n-1)/(2*r))
.2897326871923714506502211457721853341644126909116947422293621066225\
555385326652788789421475224989232
```

Fortunately, well before then, we've run out of disk space. :-)  Also, the Git guys are thinking of moving to one of the SHA-256 hashes, which will raise *r* to 2<sup>256</sup>, which helps out our denominator.

(I'm using `bc` above, in which `^` is exponentiation and the `-l` library adds `e(x)` to compute *e<sup>x</sup>*.)

Comment: Great! But you forget to add practical examples, like both `git rev-list --all` can be sorted and passed to `comm -12 repo1.revs repo2.revs` ))

Comment: Well, that assumes `bash`, `sort`, and `comm`. I figured I'd leave that part as an exercise, in case you did not have those available. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To find any common revisions:

```
comm -12 <(cd repo1; git rev-list --all | sort) <(cd repo2; git rev-list --all | sort)
```

In my case both repositories share commits:

```
bash# (cd spring-petclinic; git rev-list --all) | wc -l
670

bash# (cd spring-framework-petclinic; git rev-list --all) | wc -l
571

bash# comm -12 <(cd spring-framework-petclinic/; git rev-list --all | sort) <(cd spring-petclinic; git rev-list --all | sort) | wc -l
427
```